# Openlayer-3 drawend and double click event handling

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3, geoserver

i have added a draw intraction on the map and also the double click event handler also

```
on(this._map,'dblclick',lang.hitch(this,"_handleDoubleClick"));
```

when the feature is double clicked i need to add the Edit intraction so i have the double click event handler

But when i double click draw-end event is triggering because drawing LineString

```
var drawOptions = {
        source : this.layer.source,
        clickTolerance : 12
}
```

i have tried giving the clickTolerance also

How can i handle this? if the Point is drawing this issue will not come :)